Laptop causes noise to effects pedal when hooked up via USB
I use a BOSS SY-300 on my guitar pedalboard (don't laugh; it's very versatile), but when I hook up the USB to my laptop to use the editing software, I get a big increase in noise from the SY-300 to my headphones (it also happens with my amp). Everything is plugged into a single power source. If I unplug the laptop power source, the noise disappears.

Do you have any idea how I can troubleshoot the problem?

Can you elaborate on "running through my audio channels to my amp"? I.e., what was meant to put sound into the computer is generating sound out?

I'd like to suggest a test: Can you run your laptop on battery, disconnect it from everything but the SY-300, plug in headphones to the laptop and see if the noise is on the headphones? It's possible the noise is caused by some kind of ground loop, and this test will help to determine how likely that is (if no noise, then probably a ground loop). Oh wait, if the noise is coming from the SY-300, can you do the same test but plug the headphones into the SY-300 instead of the laptop?

Are there any other cables next to the USB cable between your SY-300 and laptop, or are all other cables/wires at least a foot away from the USB cable?

@AndyBonner I've edited the post to answer your question.

@ToddWilcox I've edited the post to answer your question.

@SottoVoce I've edited the post to answer your question.


If I unplug the laptop power source, the noise disappears.

You have a ground loop and/or noisy laptop power supply. Essentially, the laptop power supply is adding noise to the ground plane of the laptop which is connected to the ground plane of the USB connection which is connected to the audio ground in the SY-300. At least one of those devices has some kind of design flaw that doesn't matter unless you connect them like this, which is why the device was sold with the flaw.
If any of the USB cable, laptop power supply, or laptop are affordable and low quality, it's possible replacing one or more of them might fix the issue.
If you have a different computer or laptop to try, that could help you narrow it down. Same with different USB cables or power supplies.

Definitely a ground loop issue. I had this problem even with a re-amp box ground lift which should have resolved it (worked on desktop) but when switching to a laptop I had to use a 3 to 2 prong adapter for the laptop power supply (USA). I don't think this is the best solution however: depending on building wiring and equipment a person might be setting themselves up to be the path to ground (read: electrocution) when touching e.g. a microphone etc.

There are devices that can be used that don't cut the ground such as Hum X Ebtech (never used it) which is called a "ground line voltage filter"> These are not for EMI/cell phone/HDD 60hz hum which is a separate issue

Not a ground loop because they're plugged into the same power source?

@empty Being plugged into separate power sources is one way to get a ground loop between devices that are properly designed and built. Improperly designed or built devices or damaged devices could create potentials on their ground planes.

It was the laptop power supply. I found another and swapped it and the noise went away.

@empty Awesome! I always preferred happy endings :-)
